# asp c# get the PDF filename

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just start to learn asp.net and c#. I have a problem getting the file name of the PDF file in a form which is using the Post method.

```
<div class="form" id="pnl_Form" style="display:block ;">
    <form id="form1"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  target="frmUpload"  action="/include/ajax.aspx?op=upload" >
        <div>
            Step 1. Choose a PDF to be converted: <i>(File limit <%=Global.MaxFileSize %> MB)</i>
            <div class="form-val">               
            <input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" class="txt" />
            </div>   
        </div>


        <div class="form-btn"> <a href="javascript:void()" class="btn-green" onclick="upload()"><span style="padding:0px 50px 0px 45px;">Send</span></a></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

    </form> 

    <iframe id="frmUpload" name="frmUpload"  style="display:none"></iframe>
</div>
```

And the PDF would be uploaded and be converted using a 3rd party conversion tool. I need to show the user the name of the uploaded PDF when the conversion is finished.

```
   <div class="form" id="pnl_Success">
    <div class="form-text">
        <h4>Conversion Successfully!</h4>

        <p>File name: <%= Request.Files[0].FileName %> </p>

        <div class="form-btn" style="margin-left:20%;"> <a href="/account/uploadlist.html" class="btn-green"><span style="padding:0px 20px 0px 15px;">Go to download</span></a></div>
        <br>       

    </div>
</div>
```

But using Request.Files[0].FileName, the following error is shown:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out
>   of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the
>   collection. Parameter name: index

However in the cs code, the Request.Files[0] is using too and the PDF can be successfully uploaded.

```
    private void Upload()
{

    int fileId = 0;
    int result = 0;
    HttpPostedFile postFile = Request.Files[0];


    //user information
    Account account = new Account();

    result = widget.Upload( postFile, out fileId) ; 

    if (result == (int)FileStatus.UploadSuccess)
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>parent.convertProgress('" + fileId + "')</script>");
    else
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>parent.failUpload(" + fileId + "," + result + ");</script>");
}
```

I also tried to use a static variable to get the value of the postFile.FileName and call the value using asp in the webpage but not working too?

In the class there is:

```
        public static string showName;
```

In the upload() function there is:

```
        showName = postFile.FileName;
```

---

Finally get the file name using Javascript, but I'm still searching for the ASP solution.

Comment: If you're using asp.net, why not use the [`<asp:FileUpload>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you don't have anything in Request.Files[0]

This is where the error is happening, it says you haven't uploaded anything. Try to write out Request.Files.Count to see if my idea is correct.

Comment: It is 0. I don't understand, the file is already uploaded and the conversion is finished, why the Request.Files gets nothing?

Comment: Are you redirecting to a new page when the conversion is successful? In that case, you don't send files along, hence Request.Files.Count will be 0

Comment: No, it's on the same page. The URL never changes.

Answer (score 0):

Hejner is 99% right. On the other hand you can check out an ASP FileUpload control - http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/ instead of using pure HTML. I think it would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a HTML form inside a ASP.NET form. This is the reason your `Request.Files` is empty. Use a ASP.NET file upload control within the ASP.NET form, then it'll work.

Comment: But the Request.Files is working in the cs file, why it is not working in the aspx page?

Comment: Show us more code, please, so we can see which part of code comes from which file and should be executed when. Why would `File name: <%= Request.Files[0].FileName %>` work AFTER a conversion?